# changing coordinate system

Tags: 2d, transformation

I'm currently trying to transform a system by scaling it on `x` and `y` axis and have some uncertainty. I have the general concept that scaling works as such:

[image]

My original box has corners at `(0, 0)` and `(3, 2)` and I'm asked to scale the `x` axis by `3` and the `y` axis by `-2`.

Is this what the correct solution would look like (with corners at `(0,2)` and `(6,-2)`)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the points you have, no. The new rectangle will be defined by the points (0, 0) and (6, -4). The point on the origin will not scale to a new position where are the other point you have will. Scaling by -2 in the y will flip the rectangle so instead of having a point in the bottom left and top right it will now be in the top left and bottom right.

Comment: Got it. Is [this](http://imgur.com/o9uB8nT) what it would look like?

Comment: Yes it is. Best is to remember that scaling will move things away (or if less than 0 then towards) the origin. Since a point is already at the origin it will stay there.